# Can anybody tell me what size DC jack is used on a Lenovo/Iomega PX4 NAS power supply adapter?

Tags: power-supply, nas

As the title says, I would like to know what size DC jack is used on the Iomega/Lenovo PX4 range of NAS.

I've recently just purchased a bare bones unit and need a power supply and wanted to order one ahead of its arrival and wanted to get one with greater power capacity than the standard one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a 5.5mm DC jack with 2.5mm internal pin.